# Is it possible to convert a result set from WebMatrix.Database.Query() to an XML string?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ado.net, webmatrix

I'd like to consume the result set on the client side using a jQuery script, however I'm uncertain how to convert it to XML, other than building the XML DOM string manually, which I'd prefer to avoid. Is there an automatic way to convert it or obtain it as an XML string?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of APIs for generating XML, including [Linq TO XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). However, I would serialize your server side data to JSON if you want to make it available to jQuery. The [JSON helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper) is perfect for this.